# Using Cesium in Dartium

Tags: dart, cesiumjs

I am trying to evaluate using dart for a cesium app using jsinterop libs.  Using dart2js everything works in regular chrome, but dartium will not load the map entirely, it freezes the entire tab.

Is there a way to get dartium to run cesium successfully?

If you load dartium and go to cesiums home page that also freezes: http://cesiumjs.org/
Cesium does work in the latest build of raw chromium.

Dartium version:  34.0.1847.0 (264987)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the latest version of dartium (36.0.1985.49 (275358)) in the 'early adopter' section of https://www.dartlang.org/tools/download.html

It works!